# Mapping graphs to themselves, e.g. the meta-graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I'm looking for any prior work on a (for lack of a better word) meta-graph. Let $M=(V,E)$ be a a meta-graph with vertex and edge set $V,E$. The meta-graph is formed by mapping a set of graphs $G = \{g_1, g_2, \ldots \}$ onto the vertices of $V$, one-to-one $g_1 \rightarrow v_1, g_2 \rightarrow v_2, \ldots$ and there is an edge between $v_i, v_j \in V$ if $g_i$ and $g_J$ share some property.

**Example #1**:
For example, let $G$ be the set of valid $k$ colorings over the complete graph $K_n$ and let the edge function be a single color change, e.g. $v_i$ and $v_j$ share an edge if a single color change in $g_i$ would result in $g_j$.

**Example #2:**
Let $G$ include $K_n$ and all of it's subgraphs. The edge function is such that 
$v_i$ and $v_j$ share an edge if the number of edges and vertices $g_i$ is exactly one less than $g_j$.

The question is a reference request. I'd like to know the proper name for the "meta-graph" and what kinds have been studied.

Comment: It seems to me that you call a meta-graph are categories? Precisely, categories of graphs with graph homomorphisms.

Comment: @Graffitics sorry for the basic question, but would the given examples shown count as graph homomorphisms?

Comment: Not really, because you can't compose these operations (i.e. the relation is not transitive); in a sense, the corresponding meta-graphs lacks algebraic structure. If you require the underlying operation to be composable (e.g. homomorphisms, colored homomorphisms, embeddings, ...), then you get something that's algebraically more interesting, and has been studied.

Comment: There's also something different that looks like your examples, the concept of Hamming graph.